# Print values less than specified number for all fields with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a tab-delimited file and I am interested in printing all values less than or equal to 1.

input data:

```
OG1_1908    1   1   1   1   1   
OG1_1909    1   1   1   1   1   
OG1_1910    1   1   1   1   1   
OG1_1000    5   6   6   0   0   
OG1_1001    0   0   0   13  2   
OG1_3987    1   0   1   0   0
OG1_3998    1   0   1   0   0
OG1_1002    2   7   2   1   2       
OG1_3999    1   0   1   0   0   
OG1_4000    1   0   1   0   0
```

Output data:

```
OG1_3987    1   0   1   0   0
OG1_3998    1   0   1   0   0   
OG1_3999    1   0   1   0   0   
OG1_4000    1   0   1   0   0   
OG1_1908    1   1   1   1   1   
OG1_1909    1   1   1   1   1   
OG1_1910    1   1   1   1   1
```

I have the following one-liner but I feel this isn't the smartest command because I specify each conditional for each field I am interested in. Is there a better awk command that could  handle any number of fields for my input data file? Thank you

```
awk -F '\t' '{ if ( $2 <= 1 && $3 <= 1 && $4 <= 1 && $5 <= 1 && $6 <=1) print $0 }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through your fields starting from second column till end of line. If you encounter a field with value greater than 1, move to next line. If not, print the line.

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i>1){next}}1' file
OG1_1908    1   1   1   1   1   
OG1_1909    1   1   1   1   1   
OG1_1910    1   1   1   1   1   
OG1_3987    1   0   1   0   0
OG1_3998    1   0   1   0   0
OG1_3999    1   0   1   0   0   
OG1_4000    1   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: Oh now that I see, is this your first approach? I thought it was different. If it was, let me know and I will delete my answer!!

Comment: @fedorqui No, my first approach was using `gsub` but I realized that would break under certain conditions. By the time I edited you had already posted yours. No need for delete. You have an explicit `print` which would be helpful for others to view different ways to approach this. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Loop through all fields and skip line whenever one is `>1`. Then, `print`, which will only happen if the line was not skipped.

```
$ awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i>1) next } {print}' file
OG1_1908    1   1   1   1   1   
OG1_1909    1   1   1   1   1   
OG1_1910    1   1   1   1   1   
OG1_3987    1   0   1   0   0
OG1_3998    1   0   1   0   0
OG1_3999    1   0   1   0   0   
OG1_4000    1   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: This command worked, thank you for your help. I have another question. I am fairly new to bash commands. Sometimes you see: cat input | awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i>1) next } {print}'. Does the cat command make the program run faster?

Comment: The cat command makes the program run (negligibly) slower.  Google UUOC.

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk '{p = 1; for( i = 2; i <= NF; i++ ) if ( $i > 1 ) p = 0} p'
```